# Why does Firebase Realtime db work in incognito, etc but not Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm just getting started with the Firebase ecosystem and doing some investigating before committing to a GCloud database implementation (Datastore vs. Firestore). My target client is Web/browser and my backend services will be in AppEngine.

Tinkering with the [cloud messaging quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/README.md) example, it seems that FCM doesn't work in several scenarios (incognito mode, Safari, if permission blocked). However, the [friendly chat demo](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/tree/master/web) that uses realtime db updates does appear to work in these scenarios.

High level could anyone explain why?

My goal is to subscribe to events for the client to update state, etc without the use of polling. It seems overkill to put these into firestore just to bypass the notifications permission requirements. Any insight is appreciated. These events could be dispatched from several different backend services and are not exclusively bound to db records.

**Update**
For what I wanted to do, I was able to simply use Firestore and had no needs that targeted specific devices that merited using FCM. Firestore came out of beta since I posted this question and works well for live subscribing to queries that update local state, which is ultimately what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FCM client works on the promise that it can identify your browser, even when the page is not open. So it needs to persistently be able to identify the browser. It uses an Instance Token for that, which I assume it persists in the local storage of your browser. And since an incognito window has its own local storage, it becomes a separate instance ID.

The Firebase Realtime Database itself does not persist any information about the instance. Instead you pass in all the necessary information when you initialize the `FirebaseApp` instance, and then get a `DatabaseReference`. Since the incognito window runs the same code, it's accessing the same information in the database, and thus seeing the same result.

Note that this would be different if you use Firebase Authentication in combination with the Realtime Database. Auth will persist the user token to local storage, so that won't be shared with the incognito window.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Frank! That makes sense. 

If my goal is to notify browser clients of state changes, would it make more sense to create a sort of event log in Firebase/Firestore to leverage the live updates than leverage FCM given the restrictions? The event log would have "topics" encoded in so you would just query for the "topics" you care about. Using the friendly chat analogy, you might have a topic of the room id, etc? 

Is there a better google cloud product to accomplish this? I've been reading up on pub/sub but that seems more server to server.

Comment: For  me it mostly depends on whether I want to deliver notifications if the app is not active (i.e. is not open in any tab). If I don't need delivery of push notifications, I will always use one of the database options (Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore). I try to stay within Firebase for these things, since then I know there are client-side SDKs, and I'm already familiar with their configuration.